# Java EE auth to JAX-RS

Tags: java, api, authentication, jakarta-ee

What is the best way to authenticate users to a rest API when it's built with Java EE technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The world is your oyster but generally you are looking at using the same methods for authenticating that you'd use on a website. Do whatever you think is necessary. You could choose from;

- simple username/password
- OAuth
- digitally signing the request (and potentially encrypting it) for example with an SSL cert
- lots of others

Answer (score 2):

There are two general approaches for an API: You are offering keys and treat every request that has a valid key as being authorized.

Or you use the methods prescribed by HTTP for authentication. In case of basic authentication a login and password.

If the users of your API are acting on behalf of THEIR users, oauth seems to be the established standard though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way, but I would use HTTPS with SSL certificates. If possible use LDAP for the password and user "administration".